# How do I perform a delete with sub-query in Diesel against a Postgres database?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I have the following schema in a Postgres database:

```
Table A {
  ID
  Name
}

Table B {
  ID FOREIGN KEY (A.ID)
}
```

I'm trying to write the following query in Diesel:

```sql
DELETE FROM B
WHERE B.ID in (SELECT ID from A WHERE A.Name = $VAR)
```

`$VAR` is a variable passed by my application.

My first attempt to write this was the following:

```
fn deleteB(conn: &PgConnection, n: &str) {
    use schema::A::dsl::*;
    use schema::A;
    use schema::B;

    let res = A::table
        .filter(Name.eq(n))
        .select(ID);
        .load(conn)
        .unwrap();
    assert!(res.len() < 2);
    let b_id: i32 = *res.iter().nth(1).unwrap_or(&0);

    let _rows = diesel::delete(
        B::table
        .filter(ID.eq(n_id))
    )
    .execute(conn)
    .unwrap();
}
```

This compiles but it doesn't work: the `SELECT` statement for the ID always returns 0. It doesn't match any of the inserted records in A even though I checked by hand they are there. I'm sure I have an error in the way the match is being done (`&str` vs `&String` maybe?), but I decided to try a different solution since I didn't like this one anyway since it has to execute two separate statements against the database.

My second attempt looks like this:

```
fn deleteB(conn: &PgConnection, n: &str) {
    use schema::A::dsl::*;
    use schema::A;
    use schema::B;

    let source = B::table.inner_join(A::table)
            .filter(Name.eq(n));
    let s = delete(source)
            .execute(conn)
            .unwrap();
}
```

This looks more Diesel-idiomatic to me (spoiler alert, I barely know the framework) but sure enough, it doesn't compile:

```
    |
410 |     let s = delete(source)
    |                    ^^^^^^ the trait `diesel::query_builder::IntoUpdateTarget` is not implemented for `diesel::query_builder::SelectStatement<diesel::query_source::joins::JoinOn<diesel::query_source::joins::Join<mobility2::schema::B::table...` (very long error)
```

I was looking into the aforementioned trait when I realised this seems like a trivial operation (the delete itself) and I would probably be better off asking for help.

How do I properly write the idiomatic Diesel code to execute the delete statement I want to execute?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) and [Diesel](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust-diesel/info) specific MRE tipsy ou can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, idiomatic Rust uses `snake_case` for variables, methods, macros, fields and modules; `UpperCamelCase` for types and enum variants; and `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for statics and constants.

Comment: *I am fundamentally misunderstanding something about the framework that someone knowledgeable* — This is possible, but do you want to mis-spend the time of this knowledgeable person as they try to decide exactly what state you are in and what you need? Instead, we can provide the full context ahead of time. SO is also about long-lived questions, and a well-formed question is valuable to more than the original asker. *point out withhout reproducing* — Perhaps, but many answers (at least good ones) test their changes before submitting. Reducing this barrier makes an answer easier to make.

Comment: See also [Deleting from an associated table with a subquery using Diesel from a postgres database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57022429/155423)

Comment: As a concrete example, I had the same solution [as the posted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60847554/155423) 12 hours ago. However, I didn't have your `mod schema` correctly defined, so I got unrelated errors. You could have had your answer *that much faster* if you had taken the time to produce a [mre].

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Diesel statements map quite literally to SQL, the query you have written would result in:

```sql
DELETE FROM TABLE B INNER JOIN TABLE A ON … WHERE name = $1
```

That's not valid SQL, so it results in a compile time error.

To get the query you want to write, you need to do something like:

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate diesel;

use diesel::delete;
use diesel::prelude::*;

mod schema {
    table! {
        A(ID) {
            ID -> Integer,
            name -> Text,
        }
    }

    table! {
        B(ID) {
            ID -> Integer,
        }
    }

    allow_tables_to_appear_in_same_query!(A, B);
}

fn deleteB(conn: &PgConnection, n: &str) {
    use schema::A;
    use schema::B;

    let s = delete(B::table)
        .filter(B::ID.eq_any(A::table.filter(A::name.eq(n)).select(A::ID)))
        .execute(conn)
        .unwrap();
}
```

Comment: I've fixed the code, so it compiles now (assuming a correctly generated `schema.rs` file)

Comment: [The docs say](http://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/expression_methods/trait.ExpressionMethods.html#method.eq_any) to use [`any`](http://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/pg/expression/dsl/fn.any.html) instead when dealing with Postgres — is that important?

Comment: Not really. `any` provides a bit better performance if you bind an array of values there. For sub queries this is not relevant. I'm not even sure if `any` would accept a subquery.

Comment: Beautiful, this is exactly what I was looking for! Specifically, the eq_any operator cleared the whole thing up for me. Thank you!