# How do I perform an `UPDATE FROM` using Diesel?

Tags: sql, rust, rust-diesel

Suppose I have three tables, `a`, `b` and `c`:

```sql
create table c (
  id serial primary key,
  can_edit_b boolean not null
);
create table b (
  id serial primary key,
  value text not null
);
create table a (
  id serial primary key,
  c_id integer not null references c(id),
  b_id integer not null references b(id)
);
```

I want to update `b` (given an id for an instance of `c`) so long as that instance of `c` is referenced by an instance of `a` which also references `b` and `c.can_edit_b` is true. The SQL for what I want to do:

```sql
update b
set value = "some value"
from c, a
where a.b_id == b.id
where a.c_id == <user id (inserted as a Rust i32)>
where c.can_edit_b == true
```

I can't find the [relevant method/function in Diesel's API](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.4.5/diesel/?search=from) which corresponds to an SQL `from`. If I try and use `inner_join` then the compiler tells me that `inner_join` is not defined for `UpdateStatement`.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your setup and errors in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) and [Diesel-specific](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) MRE tips you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join the tables, apply a filter, then use that as the update condition:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate diesel; // 1.4.5, features = ["postgres"]

use diesel::prelude::*;

table! {
    a {
        id -> Integer,
        c_id -> Integer,
        b_id -> Integer,
    }
}

table! {
    b {
        id -> Integer,
        value -> VarChar,
    }
}

table! {
    c {
        id -> Integer,
        can_edit_b -> Bool,
    }
}

joinable!(a -> b (b_id));
joinable!(a -> c (c_id));

allow_tables_to_appear_in_same_query!(a, b, c);

fn example(arg: i32) {
    let all_joined = a::table.inner_join(b::table).inner_join(c::table);
    let matching_rows = all_joined
        .filter(a::c_id.eq(arg))
        .filter(c::can_edit_b.eq(true));

    let update_stmt = diesel::update(b::table)
        .filter(b::id.eq_any(matching_rows.select(b::id)))
        .set(b::value.eq("some value"));

    println!("{}", diesel::debug_query::<diesel::pg::Pg, _>(&update_stmt));
}

fn main() {
    example(42);
}
```

This generates SQL that differs from yours, but should result in the same outcome:

```sql
UPDATE "b"
SET "value" = $1
WHERE "b"."id" IN
    (SELECT "b"."id"
     FROM (("a"
            INNER JOIN "b" ON "a"."b_id" = "b"."id")
           INNER JOIN "c" ON "a"."c_id" = "c"."id")
     WHERE "a"."c_id" = $2
       AND "c"."can_edit_b" = $3) -- binds: ["some value", 42, true]
```

See also:

- [How do I perform a delete with sub-query in Diesel against a Postgres database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60836040/155423)